# How young is typically “young”?

Tags: career-path

I was reading about a “young researcher award” recently being attributed in my field to a colleague who is 40 years old (and has had a permanent research position for 12 years now). It may be viewed as borderline ridiculous, so I must ask: in this context, how young is typically “young”? For the purpose of this special projects/grants/awards, how do research and funding organizations define “young”?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some awards presented to people aged 35 and below:

1. The [Young Scientist Awards](http://www.a-star.edu.sg/tabid/443/default.aspx) of the Singapore National Academy of Science
2. The [Young Scientist of the Year Award](http://www.esrf.eu/UsersAndScience/users_org/YoungScientistAward) of the European Synchrotron Radiation Facility
3. The [Young Scientist Award](http://csirhrdg.res.in/ysa1.htm) of the Council of Scientific & Industrial Research
4. The [WMO Research Award for Young Scientists](http://www.wmo.int/pages/about/awards/youngscientistsaward.html) of the World Meteorological Organization
5. The [Young Scientist Award](http://epdic13.grenoble.cnrs.fr/spip.php?article18) of the European Powder Diffraction Conference

There are many more; just use a search engine to search for the terms *"young scientist" award 35*.

A similar list of awards can be found with a search for *"young scientist" award 40*.

Answer (score 20):

The Fields medal also has an age cutoff of 40 (Andrew Wiles being the most recent example of someone who missed the age cutoff for an otherwise sure award).

Grant agencies usually define "young" in terms of "years since Ph.D", or "years in academic position" with the typical cutoff being 6 or so.

Note that while for most things*, 40 might not be considered "young", in many disciplines you might only get your first academic position near that age (especially in biology).

* politics being the other venue where 40 would be considered young :)

Comment: I missed the cut-off too.

Answer (score 13):

"Young" does in fact have many different connotations. For example, in the [ERC Starting Grant](http://erc.europa.eu/starting-grants) program, applicants can have been out of graduate school for as many as *twelve* years before applying as a "Starter" (or "Consolidator"). So technically, they're still "young," according to that program, but not what we would normally think of as "young."

But, in general, "young" can refer in terms of age (in which case I've normally seen the cutoff be about 35 or so), or in terms of relative experience in the field (typically five years, although it can be shorter or longer, depending on the field or country).

Answer (score 11):

In economics, the most prestigious award outside the nobel prize is probably the John Bates Clark Medal (most winners go on to eventually receive the Nobel too). It is awarded biannually to only one person, so in a sense is even more prestigious than the Nobel (which is awarded annually to typically more than 1); to who is deemed the leading 'young' researcher under 40. So 40 as a cutoff for 'young' doesn't surprise me much, but there are obviously no hard rules.

Answer (score 9):

The EU has the program [FET OPEN Young Explorers](http://cordis.europa.eu/fp7/ict/fet-open/ye_en.html), where young is defined as:

> A project must be led by a young researcher, and the leadership by young researchers of all work packages is also required. No more than six years should have elapsed between the award of a Ph.D. (or equivalent) for each such young researcher and the date of submission of the short proposal.

I have also seen postdoc position reserved for people who obtained their PhD less than 5 years ago, but I can't find the reference back.

Comment: Just to add to the list, the young scholar award for [US criminology by the American Society of Criminology](http://www.asc41.com/awards/RuthShonleCavanYoungAward.html) is "by someone who has received the Ph.D., MD, LL.D. or a similar graduate degree no more than five years before the year of the award".

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes what is still considered "young" also depends on the specific situation of the individual: I've seen exceptions described in the areas of paternity leaves, compulsory military service, or receiving additional clinical training.

Answer (score 0):

The NSF [CAREER](http://www.nsf.gov/funding/pgm_summ.jsp?pims_id=503214) award (Faculty Early Career Development Program) is a grant for "young" scientists, and requires that winners have the title "assistant professor." This typically means that the person has spent < 6 years in a tenure track academic position. Of course, such a person need not be "young" -- someone who worked 2 years in industry before grad school, spent 6 years doing a PhD, 2 years of postdoc, and then spent 5 years as an assistant professor might win one of these awards and be nearly 40.